# Using Admob & Adcolony in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob, adcolony

first, I hope I understand because I can not speak English well.
I am using Unity. Unity version is 5.6.1f1.
Admob version and Adcolony version is latest.

Originally, Using Admob + Unity Ads mediation.
At this time, admob banner load and show successfull.

after, i'm add the AdColoy.
but, admob banner load fail. 
so, Test the admob test banner, result is load succeeded.

I do not know why the banner failed ad requests.
adUnitId is no problem.

Please help me if you have any experience with this or if you know the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Let me get this straight. After you integrated AdColony, your admob banners stopped showing. But they do work when you try to show test banners. I'm assuming this is on android.

If test ads work, and real ads don't, then there's probably something wrong on the Admob dashboard. For example, you may have an X ads limit for the active campaign, perhaps you hit that limit while testing the app - if that is the case, the change in behavior has nothing to do with adding AdColony.

If Admob and AdColony have no conflicting jars that you deleted while trying to make the build work, then it's either a problem on the dashboard or with your AdManager that is loading/showing the ads.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Let's check it once.